# Код запускается но, ничего не происходит

Tags: python, модули

Есть код который должен перемещать файлы, но после запуска ничего не происходит

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import os
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

folder_track = '/Users/Anton/Downloads'
folder_dest = '/users/Anton/Desktop/Music'

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_track):
            extension = filename.split(".")
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == "mp3"):
                file = folder_track + "/" + filename
                new_path = folder_dest + "/" + filename
                os.replace(folder_track + "/" + filename, new_path + "/" + filename)



handle = FileSystemEventHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(handle, folder_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Comment: а что у вас делает вот эта строка `handle = FileSystemEventHandler()` ?

Comment: Навскидку: в коде опечатка. Должно быть `handle = Handler()`

Comment: Ну, он что так `handle = FileSystemEventHandler()` что `так handle = Handler()` не работает. Без этой строки вообще не работает

Comment: @RrIiDdIiKk ну то есть вы понятия не имеете, что в этой строке написано?

Comment: @cauf да. Ну насколько я понимаю вызывает FileSystemEventHandler или Handler. Просто нигде не могу найти документацию к этому модулю.

Comment: @cauf даже в документации ничего не сказано про Handler()

Comment: @RrIiDdIiKk прочтите учебник по ООП вообще и наследованию в частности, что бы не писать таких глупостей. Класс `Handler` наследуется вами собственноручно от `FileSystemEventHandler`. Вы нигде не найдете по нему документацию, так как только что в коде его создали

Comment: @cauf ну это все равно ничего не меняет, код не работает

Comment: @RrIiDdIiKk а без понимания того, что вы хотите сделать и что делаете на самом деле код и не заработает. Здесь нет ясновидящих, что бы прочесть ваши мысли, а о сути задачи вы так и не рассказали внятно. По коду не понятно, чего именно вы хотели добиться и где возможные проблемы. Зато отлично видно, что вы не понимаете базовых концепций того, как этот код был написан

Answer (score -1):

Нужный мне функционал можно достигнуть достаточно лёгким способом

```
import os 
import shutil as shu

folder_track = '/Users/anton/Downloads'
end_folder = '/Users/anton/Desktop/Music'
filename = os.listdir(folder_track)

file = input('Форамат файла ')
moving = input('rev?')


if moving == 'n':
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_track):
        extension = filename.split(".")

        if moving == 'n':
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == file):
                extension = '.'.join(extension)
                shu.move(folder_track + "/" + filename, end_folder + "/" + filename)
else:
    for filename in listdir(end_folder):
        extension = filename.split(".")

        if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == file):
            extension = '.'.join(extension)
            shu.move(end_folder + "/" + filename, folder_track + "/" + filename)
```

Но если нужно всё-таки чтобы запустил и забыл дальше он работает сам то тогда нужна будет библиотека watchdog

Comment: Этот код не является альтернативой к приведенному в вопросе и не решает поставленной проблемы. Это плохой ответ на вопрос